# change color links inside div when mouseover div

Tags: html, css

I try change color links inside div , when i put cursor inside div , but i can´t get results

```css
#pag_number {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #111;
}
#pag_number a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A9A713;
}
```

```html
<div id="pag_number"><a href="#1">1</a>
</div>
```

I try using the css i put until , but no get works and never when i put my cursor over the div called **pag_number** get change color links inside

Thank´s for help , regards

Comment: Negative , ??? Why ?

Comment: Other negative ha ha incredible , this website ridiculous

Comment: Please, don’t blame the website for the down votes.

Comment: I tell all i want and if you don´t like your problem , it´s ridiculous my questions it´s normal , no have problem, ridiculous put negatives , in community exists tolerande all people , ridiculous let some people put negative by all , this kind of things very bad for community

Comment: First of all: I feel sorry for you, that your question was down voted. I experienced this myself, it doesn't feel good. Secondly this platform is for you to find a solution for your coding problem, but therefore it demands from to do some research by yourself. It's purpose isn't just posting a question and hope for an answer. Actually questions similar to yours were already answered. It wouldn't have hard to find it by yourself. 3. Stay polite, Sir!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change color of `child element` while hovering `parent` you need to set css in this format `parent:hover > child` in your case `#pag_number:hover a`

```css
#pag_number {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #111;
}
#pag_number:hover a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #A9A713;
}
```

```html
<div id="pag_number"><a href="#1">1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank´s i give you possitive , regards